# How do I insert a small title into the middle of the top graphical line of a frame like environment containing alltt?

Tags: verbatim, framed

I require an environment to

1. layout lines of text with line ending control (like poetry),
2. with proper kerning and inter-word spacing,
3. within a frame that can span pages,
4. such that a small title can be inserted into the middle of the top graphical line of the frame,
5. and such that typesetting commands are still available via some mechanism.

I have been using the following:

```
\newenvironment{QUOTE}[1]
{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
{\def\sss{$\vdots$}}%
{\def\sss{#1}}%  
\Verbatim[label=\sss, frame=single, commandchars=@\{\}]}
{\endVerbatim}
```

For example:

```
\begin{QUOTE}{75.1}
As the lion in our teargarten remembers the nenuphars of his Nile 
 @emph{( shall Ariuz forget Arioun}
   @emph{or Boghas the baregams of the Marmarazalles from Marmeniere? )} it may be, 
 tots wearsense full
  a naggin in twentyg have sigilposted what in our brievingbust,
  @underline{the besieged} bedreamt @underline{him} stil and solely of @underline{those lililiths} 
  undeveiled which had undone him, gone for age, 
 and knew not the watchful treachers at his wake, and theirs to stay. 
Fooi, fooi, chamermissies! Zeepyzoepy, larcenlads! Zijnzijn Zijnzijn!
\end{QUOTE}
```

[image]

The problem is requirement 2. With verbatim, kerning and inter-word spacing looks terrible! However, I am using the framing features of verbatim to create a frame with a title in the top line.

I can solve all my requirements except 4, using a `framed` environment with an inner `alltt` environment:

```
\newenvironment{QUOTENEW}[1]
{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
{\def\sss{$\vdots$}}%
{\def\sss{#1}}%  
\begin{framed}\begin{alltt}\normalfont}
{\end{alltt}\end{framed}}
```

For example:

```
\begin{QUOTENEW}{75.1}
As the lion in our teargarten remembers the nenuphars of his Nile 
 \emph{( shall Ariuz forget Arioun}
  \emph{or Boghas the baregams of the Marmarazalles from Marmeniere? )} it may be, 
 tots wearsense full
  a naggin in twentyg have sigilposted what in our brievingbust,
  \underline{the besieged} bedreamt \underline{him} stil and solely of \underline{those lililiths} 
  undeveiled which had undone him, gone for age, 
 and knew not the watchful treachers at his wake, and theirs to stay. 
Fooi, fooi, chamermissies! Zeepyzoepy, larcenlads! Zijnzijn Zijnzijn!
\end{QUOTENEW}
```

[image]

Hence my question could reduce to the following.

- How do I insert a small title into the middle of the top graphical line of a framed environment (as with the verbatim environment)?

Alternatively.

- How can I achieve 1. to 5. above?

**Bonus marks if I do not need to replace *every* line ending with a newline marker.**

Comment: Have you looked into the ``tcolorbox`` package?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used the `tcolorbox` package to create a box and then use this box in `QUOTE`. Here is a picture of the result, showing that is indeed breakable and can span multiple pages:

[image]

Here is the MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage{alltt}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\newtcolorbox{quotebox}[1]{hbox boxed title,sharp corners,boxrule=1pt,
enhanced,breakable,attach boxed title to top center=
{yshift=-3mm,yshifttext=-1mm},colback=white,
boxed title style={size=small,colback=white,colframe=white},coltitle=black,
title={#1}}


\newenvironment{QUOTE}[1]
{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{}}%
{\def\sss{$\vdots$}}%
{\def\sss{#1}}%  
\begin{quotebox}{#1}\begin{alltt}\normalfont}
{\end{alltt}\end{quotebox}}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{QUOTE}{75.1}
As the lion in our teargarten remembers the nenuphars of his Nile 
 \emph{( shall Ariuz forget Arioun}
  \emph{or Boghas the baregams of the Marmarazalles from Marmeniere? )} it may be, 
 tots wearsense full
  a naggin in twentyg have sigilposted what in our brievingbust,
  \underline{the besieged} bedreamt \underline{him} stil and solely of \underline{those lililiths} 
  undeveiled which had undone him, gone for age, 
 and knew not the watchful treachers at his wake, and theirs to stay. 
Fooi, fooi, chamermissies! Zeepyzoepy, larcenlads! Zijnzijn Zijnzijn!

\lipsum

\end{QUOTE}


\end{document}
```

Thanks to the `breakable` option, the `tcolorbox` can span multiple pages. Note that [the documentation](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) says that:

/tcb/breakable=true|false|unlimited

- false: Sets the tcolorbox to be unbreakable.
- true: Breaks the tcolorbox from one page to another. The maximal total height of
  the upper and of the lower part is about 65536pt (ca. 2300cm or ca. 90 pages) apiece
- unlimited: Experimental code for unlimited total height of breakable boxes. For
  boxes longer than 300 pages (or even shorter ones) the compiler memory will have to
  be increased.

Comment: Thank you. Voted up, am just testing before awarding.

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly. With LaTeX there is always a way.

Comment: You're welcome. Btw: in the future it would be nice if you included the packages you use. I had to guess which ones you used to create this example (although it was not very difficult in this particular case).

Comment: Point noted. Will do in future.